# focusing an antd input component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React from 'react'
import Input as InputAnt from 'antd'

class myInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <InputAnt ref={this.inputRef}/>
    )
  }
}

export default myInput;
```

Here the InputAnt  does receive focus, but my concern is that : the 'myInput' component can be used by many other components to render an input along with so many other components. So maybe I don't want the input to get focus in all the cases wherever 'myInput' component is used, I only want to focus under particular scenarios, how can that be achieved?

Comment: Add a property https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: create prop, isCheckable and do focus only isCheckable true

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an additional prop when you are using `myinput`.

```
<myInput shouldFocus />
```

and in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook:

```
componentDidMount() {
   if (this.props.shouldFocus) {
     this.inputRef.current.focus();     
   }
}
```

and when you want to use `myInput` but don't want to focus your input just use it as:

```
<myInput />
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer if your question was answered.